# Using ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost() to create an Asp.Net post, while loading assemblies from another location

Tags: asp.net, applicationhost

I'm trying to use [CreateApplicationHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.applicationhost.createapplicationhost(VS.71).aspx) to create an Asp.Net application host for a simple web server, however I'm getting a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` when it attempts to create an instance of my marshalling object:

```
host = (MyMarshaller)ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost((MyMarshaller), virtualDir, physicalDir);
```

I believe that this error is because it cannot find the assembly containing the class MyMarshaller - if I put this assembly in the bin directory of physicalDir then everything works fine, however I don't want to do this (I also don't want to place my assembly in the GAC either).

Is there any way that I can control where CreateApplicationHost looks for my assembly? (Note that `MyMarshaller` class is conted in the same assembly as the above line of code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that it isn't possible to do this, however the [Cassini](https://web.archive.org/web/20120511060641/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx) source revealed an alternative solution.

---

**Update**

The above link no longer works, however the [CassiniDev project](https://web.archive.org/web/20180120042341/http://cassinidev.codeplex.com:80/) on CodePlex appears to be pretty close (possibly a derivative work) and contains the same solution.

The solution is to avoid using `CreateApplicationHost` and "do it yourself" instead - in this case use reflection to create an instance of the internal "BuildManagerHost" type and call "RegisterAssembly", like so

```
/// <remarks>
/// This is Dmitry's hack to enable running outside of GAC.
/// There are some errors being thrown when running in proc
/// </remarks>
private object CreateWorkerAppDomainWithHost(string virtualPath, string physicalPath, Type hostType,int port)
{
    // create BuildManagerHost in the worker app domain
    //ApplicationManager appManager = ApplicationManager.GetApplicationManager();
    Type buildManagerHostType = typeof(HttpRuntime).Assembly.GetType("System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerHost");
    IRegisteredObject buildManagerHost = ApplicationManager.CreateObject(_appId, buildManagerHostType, virtualPath,
                                                                  physicalPath, false);
    
    // call BuildManagerHost.RegisterAssembly to make Host type loadable in the worker app domain
    buildManagerHostType.InvokeMember("RegisterAssembly",
                                      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                      null,
                                      buildManagerHost,
                                      new object[] { hostType.Assembly.FullName, hostType.Assembly.Location });
    
    // create Host in the worker app domain
    // FIXME: getting FileLoadException Could not load file or assembly 'WebDev.WebServer20, Version=4.0.1.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f7f6e0b4240c7c27' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant permission to execute. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131418)
    // when running dnoa 3.4 samples - webdev is registering trust somewhere that we are not
    return ApplicationManager.CreateObject(_appId, hostType, virtualPath, physicalPath, false);
}
```

Comment: would be interesting if you elaborated a bit on this? Especially since the link doesn't work anymore :(